# Thread safety when only one thread is writing

Tags: java, multithreading

I know if two threads are writing to the same place I need to make sure they do it in a safe way and cause no problems but what if just one thread reads and does all the writing while another just reads.

In my case I'm using a thread in a small game for the 1st time to keep the updating apart from the rendering. The class that does all the rendering will never write to anything it reads, so I am not sure anymore if I need handle every read and write for everything they both share.

I will take the right steps to make sure the renderer does not try to read anything that is not there anymore but when calling things like the player and entity's getters should I be treating them in the same way? or would setting the values like x, y cords and Booleans like "alive" to volatile do the trick?

My understanding has become very murky on this and could do with some enlightening

Edit: The shared data will be anything that needs to be drawn and moved and stored in lists of objects.
For example the player and other entity's;

Comment: Not sure but I guess you just need to ensure that reader thread has up to date information. Take a look at `volatile` keyword.

Comment: What is exactly the shared data? an array? a list of objects?

Comment: Anything that needs to be drawn and moved will be shared and yes lists of objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the given information it is not possible to exactly specify a solution, but it is clear that you need some kind of method to synchronize between the threads. The issue is that as long as the write operations are not *atomic* that you could be reading data at the moment that it is being updates. This means that you for instance get an old y-coordinate with a new x-coordinate.

Basically you only do not need to worry about synchronization if both threads are only *reading* the information or - even better - if all the data structures are immutable (so both threads *can not* modify the objects). The best way to proceed is to think about which operations need to be atomic first, and then create a solution to make the operations atomic.

Don't forget: get it working, get it right, get it optimized (in that order).

Comment: Your right, right now the renderer only need to know the cords and a couple Booleans to check if it should render. If I work on sharing this info safely the rest will make more sense as I go. Thank you very much sir

Answer (score 0):

You could have problems in this case if list's sizes are variable and you don't synchronize the access to them, consider this:

- read-only thread reads mySharedList size and it sees it is 15; at that moment its CPU time finishes and read-write thread is given the CPU
- read-write thread deletes an element from the list, now its size is 14.
- read-only thread is again granted CPU time, it tries to read the last element using the (now obsolete) size it read before being interrupted, you'll have an Exception.